# How can I ask for an Administrator Login in an OSX Swift Application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, applescript

I'm currently trying to make an application only open if an administrator login is entered into a dialog box. I've tried using an AppleScript under the following method:

```
set adminLogin to do shell script "" with administrator privileges
display dialog adminLogin
```

This displays the dialog I'd like, and I was able to throw this into an NSTask to perform it. I can even grab the output and use that to close the application under and `if` statement.

I'd like to be using the actual application rather than osascript to mention that it requires an administrator login to continue, and this scpt file vanishes as soon as I compile, build, and archive this for actual usage, meaning I'd have to re-add this file post-creation to all of the clients I am making this for. It doesn't seem too effective for the fact that it relies on a different task for a quick login that could possibly be exploited rather than using the same process that the application is holding.

Is there a way I can programmatically ask for an administrator login to continue opening the application? Could I use `CoreLocation` and-or could I use `AuthorizationServices()` to perform this task?

Comment: Is it for a desktop application submitted to Mac App Store?

Comment: No @ElTomato, I don't plan on submitting this to the App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `LocalAuthentication` framework. There is a policy for `deviceOwnerAuthentication` which handles both Touch ID and device passcode authentication.

LocalAuthentication Framework Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication

and

deviceOwnerAuthentication:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lapolicy/1514164-deviceownerauthentication

Comment: This is for an OSX application, not iOS. And if you're meaning Touch ID from the new Touchbar, we're using the 2015 Macbook Air models.

Comment: @dylan The LocalAuthentication framework is supported by macOS from 10.10 onwards. It supports both Touch ID and device passcode. Though you can specify the policy most suitable for your user base.